# Is it possible to use javascript to get the currently playing Itunes track

Tags: javascript, html, itunes

I am looking to see if it's, first, possible to even use javascript to get the currently playing Itunes song, and if so, how?

A use case along the lines of:

1. User clicks a link
2. An alert pops up displaying song name, artist and album.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean JS running in a **browser**?  There'd be a fundamental security problem if a browser could get any information from a desktop application without first asking your permission, don't you think?

Comment: Yes. Running in a browser. I don't want it t get any information, I am asking about a specific piece of information only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly, no. If the data from iTunes is sent to a service like [last.fm](http://www.last.fm/), it can be fetched there on a regular interval to see what they are listening to. Something similar to https://github.com/niklasvh/jquery.plugin.listening